# Removing cygwin terminal window decorations

Tags: cygwin

I'm looking for a simple way to remove the window decorations of my standard Cygwin terminal window (essentially running it in full-screen / full-screen modulo Windows start bar mode).
Is this supported in Cygwin, or does that require a patch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If full screen is what you really want, hit alt+enter (by default) to toggle fullscreen with mintty. If you want to get rid of the scroll bar, you can go to options->window and set scroll bar to none.